# Return a text value based upon another numerical value compared to a range of numerical values

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with three numerical values in A1 though A3. In A4 I have a formula that utilizes A1 through A3 to return a numerical value. The numerical value compared to a range, I would like to have return a text value. The rangee are >1500 = Blue, 1000 to 1499.99 = Green, 500 to 999.99 = Orange, and <500 = Red.

I need help developing the formula to do the above task. I have already tried VLOOKUP and MATCH to attempt this, with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you're asking, especially this sentence: `The numerical value compared to a range, I would like to have return a text value.`

If I understand right, you have a number in A4 based on numbers in A1 through A3.  Then in another cell (let's say B4), you want a string (blue, green, etc.) based on the value in A4.  If that is correct, you could use nested if's like this in B4:

```
=if(A4>=1500,"Blue",if(A4>=1000,"Green",if(A4>=500,"Orange","Red")))
```

Notice that I used greater-than-or-equal-to (`>=`) because otherwise the number 1500 will not be included in Blue or Green.

Comment: Thank you. Seems to be working. Sorry about the explanation, it took me awhile to figure out how to explain the situation.